# How to encode a string to SHA-1 on windows using the command line?

Tags: windows, shell, encryption, sha

I can only use the command line for this task, how would you convert `echo -n "mystringtoencode" | sha1sum` so it works on windows?

Or more broadly, what is the command to encode a **string** with **sha-1**  on windows?

Thanks!

Comment: A 2 line Python program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [a Microsoft Support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/889768/how-to-compute-the-md5-or-sha-1-cryptographic-hash-values-for-a-file):

```
FCIV -md5 -sha1 path\filename.ext
```

It doesn't look like it's available normally (my up-to-date Win10 doesn't have it). You'll have to download it.

If your scenario lets you use PowerShell, there's the [Get-FileHash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash?view=powershell-6) command which has MD5 and a number of versions of SHA. This might be your best no-download option.

If you really want Windows to have all the small tools that Linux has, you can get a big list of them by downloading [GOW (GNU On Windows)](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki) and adding it's binaries to your path. This includes sha1sum. These are Windows binaries running in the Windows kernel.

There's always the [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) which also has a lot of Linux tools running in a more Linux-like environment but I think that might be a bit over kill for hashing files. These will be Linux binaries running on a version of the Linux kernel. It's actually not bad.

Comment: Microsoft Support page only explains how to do it with a file, not with a string, but GOW solved it for me! Thanks!

Comment: Actually it didn't, windows works so differently that it ended up not working. I'm unable to generate the same SHA1 than on bash/cygwin/online tools. This is due to the `echo` function being differently implemented from what I understood from this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48836583/git-hash-object-is-yielding-different-sha1-in-powershell-cmd-and-bash but I guess this answer the question asked :)